# Can we implement Apple Pay in an Extension Keyboard?

Tags: ios, custom-keyboard, applepay

I have my custom keyboard with some stickers and on clicking sticker, I want the user to pay through Apple Pay.

So can we implement Apple Pay feature in a custom keyboard?

Comment: Is it a technical or a developer terms and agreements question?

Comment: Wouldn't you be supposed to be using In-App Purchases rather than Apple Pay directly? Apple wants their cut!

Comment: No, Actually I wanted to to use Apple Pay only.